# Single threaded timer and/or interval inside a Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, timer, task-parallel-library, scheduling

I want to run a function on an interval, inside of a Task. Something like,

```
       Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            while (notCanceled()) {
                doSomething();
                Thread.Sleep(interval); 
            }
        });
```

Is it a bad idea to use Thread.Sleep() here? The task is long running, and the sleep time may also be very long (minutes, maybe even hours).

One alternative is to use either System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer. However both of these would cause an additional thread to spawn (the Elapsed events occur on a new threadpool thread). So for every repeating task, there would be 2 threads instead of 1. The Task is already asynchronous so I'd prefer not to complicate things in this way.

Yet another way that behaves similarly is to use ManualResetEvent,

```
    ManualResetEvent m = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    void sleep(int milliseconds)
    {
        m.WaitOne(milliseconds);
    }
```

Since m.Set() would never be called, this would always wait for the right amount of time, and also be single threaded. Does this have any significant advantage over Thread.Sleep()?

Wondering what the best practice would be here.

Thoughts?

Comment: You've got the wrong idea about Timer.  It uses *one* tp-thread, a short running one.  You no longer use the expensive long running one you use now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C# 5.0 you can use:

```
while(notCanceled())
{
    doSomething();
    await Task.Delay(interval);
}
```

If you're using an earlier version your best bet is probably to use a `Timer`.

Both of the code samples you showed, involving either `Thread.Sleep` or a `ManualResetEvent` are blocking the current thread for that duration, which means your code is tying up a thread which can't do anything else until your task is canceled.  You don't want to do that.  If you use a timer, or the `await` code mentioned above, you will end up *not blocking any thread at all while waiting*, and then use up a thread pool's time only when you have productive work to be doing.

Comment: So do you suggest I use a timer inside the task or just not use task at all? I am already using the TPL extensively so that would be a bigger design change. If I use a timer inside the task, then I still have to keep the task alive while the timer is repeating the function, b/c otherwise wouldn't ContinueWith() be called on the task while the timer is still trying to do its work. Since the timers Start() method is non-blocking the task will just complete right away, I think?

Comment: @SeanThoman It doesn't matter whether you create the timer inside the task or not; all you're doing is starting the timer, not executing a bunch of code.  If you want a task that represents when the timer is run for the last time you won't want a call to `StartNew` at all; as the timer isn't representing the execution of a single method.  Use a `TaskCompletionSource` to generate a task that you can mark as completed when you are done with all of the iterations of your timer.  If you use the C# 5.0 approach shown first that's effectively done for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a very bad idea to use sleep in a loop like that.

You have a faulty understanding of timers. Creating a timer does not create a new thread. The timer sets an operating system trigger that, when the time elapses, spawns a threadpool thread. So if you write:

```
System.Threading.Timer myTimer = 
    new Timer(DoStuff, null, 
              TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

The only time there will be another thread is when the handler method (`DoStuff`) is executing.

There'd be no reason to have the task if everything it does is handled by your `DoStuff` method. If you want to cancel it, just dispose the timer.

I strongly recommend, by the way, that you not use `System.Timers.Timer`. In short, it squashes exceptions, which hides bugs. See [Swallowing exceptions is hiding bugs](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/05/19/swallowing-exceptions-is-hiding-bugs/).

Comment: I use continuations and fault handling provided by the TPL. If the Start() method (or constructor) of the timer is non-blocking, which it is, then the Task completes immediately. Using TaskCompletionSource<> is the right way perhaps.

Comment: +1 for "swallowing". Off-topic: I've read somewhere the phrase that any timer in .NET (Windows) is always aynchronous